# Multiply one part of Cell Array with a Scalar Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, partial, multiplication, scalar

I have a cell array that consits of a set of tracks like this:

```
<TL1x3> double
<TL1x3> double
<TL3x3> double
...
```

where TL stands for the track length. This value is different for each ekement, but there are always three columns: time, x coord, y coord.

From the tracking algorithm I get the x and y coord in pixels. However, I need them in nm, so I have to multiply them with a value, but only the second and third, not the first column of each element, e.g.:

```
0    5    6     x2     0    10    12
0.5  7    2    --->    0.5  14    4
1    8    1            1    16    2
...                    ...
```

and this for every element of the array.

With cellfun, I have managed to change every cell of the array, but I don't know how to change only one part. Do you have any idea how to do this...?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an anonymous function that calls `bsxfun()` and passing that to `cellfun()`. Assuming your input data is in the cell array `inputData` and the scale factor to apply is in the scalar variable `scaleFactor`;

```
scaledData = cellfun(@(X) bsxfun(@times, X, [1 scaleFactor scaleFactor]), inputData, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

I think this gives the results you want

Answer (score 1):

Given sample input:

```
c={[1 2 3]; [4 5 6]; [7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15]};
```

Then:

```
xf = sparse([1 0 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 2]);
d=cellfun(@(x) x * xf, c, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant nor efficient way, but converting your cell array to a matrix would simplify things for you:

```
A = {[0    5    6] ;
[0.5  7    2];
[1    8    1 ]}

B = cell2mat(A)

B(:,2:end) = 2*B(:,2:end)
```

Gives this in the command window:

A =

```
[1x3 double]
[1x3 double]
[1x3 double]
```

Before:

```
B =

         0    5.0000    6.0000
    0.5000    7.0000    2.0000
    1.0000    8.0000    1.0000
```

After:

```
B =

         0   10.0000   12.0000
    0.5000   14.0000    4.0000
    1.0000   16.0000    2.0000
```

You could also create a temporary cell array contanining the last 2 columns of your original cell array and then apply cellfun to it and put it back in the original. Are speed/performance an issue for you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have already experimented with cell2mat, but the problem here so far is that it results in just one long Nx3 matrix. However, in the original cell array, each element (in total something around 3000-10000) of the array contains one track, and this must be retained for the later analysis.